# Как получить срабатывание ивента кнопки в browserView?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

У меня есть код:

```js
browserView.webContents.executeJavaScript('
  let btn = document.createElement("button")
  btn.innerHTML = "Click Me"
  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    return "Button is clicked"
  })
  document.body.appendChild(btn)
').then(r=> console.log(r))
```

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы получить 'Button is clicked' в main process?

В browserView нет nodejs или electron, это стронний сайт.

Получать я хочу каждый клик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решается через `preload` для `browserView`

```js
const browserView = new BrowserView({
            webPreferences: {
                preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js') 
            }
        })
```

`preload.js`

```js
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let btn = document.createElement("button")
  btn.innerHTML = "Click Me"
  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    ipcRenderer.send('message','button is clicked')
  })
  document.body.appendChild(btn)
})
```

И... это работает! В main proccess через `ipcMain.on` получаем button is clicked